# How to highlight what is being edited in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am debating between Brackets and Visual Studio Code, One thing which I love that brackets has is that it can highlight what is being edited in the live preview of the code by clicking on the portion of the code. Is there anything like that in Visual Studio Code ?

I have attempted to google and search through the exentions but have not come up with what I am looking for.

Comment: Are you asking if Visual Studio (the full on IDE) has this same feature? Your title of your question is asking if Visual Studio Code has this feature, but then your question body asks if _Visual Studio_ has this.

Comment: For vscode, look at the Live Preview extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.live-server

Comment: @Mark I have the live preview extension, though it does not quite fill what I need, thank you anyway!